# Word for something that I am avoiding

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I want to describe tasks specifically. A task that I feel drawn to do is 'attractive' or 'alluring'. The best word for the opposite case seems to be 'repulsive', but that seems too strong. I want to say 'repelsive' but that's not a word! Any suggestions?

I am looking for an adjective.

In a sentence:

> "I have a tendency to procrastinate on ________ tasks."

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include a sample sentence showing how your word would be used. If you click on the [tag:single-word-requests] tag, you'll see that this is a requirement for all SWR questions. For further guidance, see [ask] and take our [Tour].

Comment: @KannE and which of those things do you believe are true in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

> [Repellent](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/repellent):

> > serving or tending to drive away or ward off

or

> [Daunting](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/daunting)

> > seeming difficult to deal with in anticipation; intimidating

Comment: yep I think repellent is what I'm looking for thanks.